# Redirecting the document help page for a function

Tags: r, roxygen2

within my own package, I want to redirect the appearing help page for a function to the documentation of another function. For e.g., when I click F1 key on "is.matrix()" or on "as.matrix()" in both cases the help page / documentation of "matrix()" appears. How do I realize that with my own functions?

```
abc <- function(data, ...) {  }
as.abc <- function(data, ...) {  }
is.abc <- function(x) {  }
```

I only want to implement one documentation for abc() and the documentation for as.abc() and is.abc() should be the one for abc().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those help pages appear when you press F1 on any of the functions because they are all in the same .Rd file, it's the same help page.

Comment: Thanks! Each function has its own documentation skeleton, and threfore its own .Rd file. Or how do I take care that as.abc() and is.abc() are going into only one .Rd file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `@rdname`. See e.g. http://www.iysik.com/r/roxygen2

In your case, you would do

```
#' abc-function title
#' @rdname abc
#' @export
#' @param data Document your parameters, please!
abc <- function(data, ...) {  }

#' @rdname abc
#' @export
#' @inheritParams abc
as.abc <- function(data, ...) {  }

#' @rdname abc
#' @export
#' @param x x
is.abc <- function(x) {  }
```